# Python json.load missing array hook and parse callbacks?

Tags: python, arrays, json

Why does [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), only allow `object_hook`, `parse_float`, `parse_int` and `parse_constant`?

```
json.loads(fp[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])
```

They're all essentially callbacks, the return value of which is used during parsing.

My intention was to use these callbacks to build my own representation of a JSON string by modifying the callback parameters. But without callbacks for arrays, strings or boolean - it seems rather limited.

Take this simple example:

```
import json

def _object_hook(d):
    print(d)
    return d

json.loads('{"a": [1, [2, [3]]]}', object_hook=_object_hook)
```

...resulting in only a single call to _object_hook (since there is only one object).

```
>>> {u'a': [1, [2, [3]]]}
```

Give an arbitrarily deep, nested array, the job of passing the array (recursively, or perhaps with a breadth-first/depth-first traversal) remains.

Then, strings are for some reason and exception too:

```
import json

def _object_hook(o):
    print('_object_hook', o)
    return o

def _parse_float(f):
    print('_parse_float', f)
    return f

def _parse_int(i):
    print('_parse_int', i)
    return i

def _parse_constant(c):
    print('_parse_constant', c)
    return c

json.loads('{"a": [1, [2, [3.1], ["4"]]]}',
    object_hook=_object_hook,
    parse_int=_parse_int,
    parse_float=_parse_float,
    parse_constant=_parse_constant)
```

...there is no way to handle strings ("4" is omitted in the results below):

```
('_parse_int', '1')
('_parse_int', '2')
('_parse_float', '3.1')
('_object_hook', {u'a': ['1', ['2', ['3.1'], [u'4']]]})
```

Perhaps my expectations are wrong. But it seemed wasteful to parse a JSON string into a Python dict or list, only to parse it again into a custom format.

With no array hooks or parse callbacks for strings, boolean, null, etc. Am I left with using `json.loads` and then parsing the resulting Python representation into my own Python classes?

Comment: Performance. And the hooks are not meant to allow for a wholesale replacement of the JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `json.loads` calls its `scanner` to parse the input string, and all behaviors can be hooked by reconstructing the `scanner` in your customized class.

```py
import json
from json.scanner import py_make_scanner
from json.decoder import JSONArray

class CustomizedDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def parse_array(*_args, **_kwargs):
            values, end = JSONArray(*_args, **_kwargs)
            for item in values:
                print(item)  # Is it what you want?
            return values, end

        self.parse_array = parse_array
        self.scan_once = py_make_scanner(self)

json.loads('{"a": [1, [2, [3.1], ["4"]]]}', cls=CustomizedDecoder)
```

outputs

```sh
3.1
4
2
[3.1]
['4']
1
[2, [3.1], ['4']]
```

Moreover, there are several other functions you can hook by doing exactly same things.

```py
self.object_hook = object_hook
self.parse_float = parse_float or float
self.parse_int = parse_int or int
self.parse_constant = parse_constant or _CONSTANTS.__getitem__
self.object_pairs_hook = object_pairs_hook
self.parse_object = JSONObject
self.parse_array = JSONArray
self.parse_string = scanstring
```

Comment: One thing to note here, you have to use `py_make_scanner` and not just `make_scanner` like the original implementation, as `c_make_scanner` may ignore some of those hooks. For instance, I've just spent an hour trying to debug why my `parse_string` was being ignored only to find out `c_make_scanner` ignores that property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to take a somewhat slower parsing into account, you can use the [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) parser for this (disclaimer: I am the author of that package). As YAML 1.2 is a superset of JSON for all practical purposes, you can subclass the `Constructor`:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, SafeConstructor

json_str = '{"a": [1, [2.0, True, [3, null]]]}'


class MyConstructor(SafeConstructor):
    def construct_yaml_null(self, node):
        print('null')
        data = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_null(self, node)
        return data

    def construct_yaml_bool(self, node):
        print('bool')
        data = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_bool(self, node)
        return data

    def construct_yaml_int(self, node):
        print('int')
        data = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_int(self, node)
        return data

    def construct_yaml_float(self, node):
        print('float')
        data = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_float(self, node)
        return data

    def construct_yaml_str(self, node):
        print('str')
        data = SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_str(self, node)
        return data

    def construct_yaml_seq(self, node):
        print('seq')
        for data in SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_seq(self, node):
            pass
        return data

    def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
        print('map')
        for data in SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_map(self, node):
            pass
        return data


MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_null)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_bool)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_int)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_float)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_str)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_seq)

MyConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map',
    MyConstructor.construct_yaml_map)


yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor

data = yaml.load(json_str)
print(data)
```

Just replace the code in each `construct_yaml_XYZ` method with code that creates the objects you want and return those.

The "funny business" with the `for` loop when creating a mapping/dict resp. sequence/list, is to unwrap the two step process of creating these objects (necessary for "real" YAML input to deal with recursive data structures using anchors/aliases).

The above outputs:

```
map
str
seq
int
seq
float
bool
seq
int
null
{'a': [1, [2.0, True, [3, None]]]}
```

You can also hook into the YAML parser at a lower level, but that doesn't make the implementation easier and probably only marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

[Martijn Pieters' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012059/python-json-load-missing-array-hook-and-parse-callbacks/46619040#comment78984359_46012059) had the correct approach:

> Performance. And the hooks are not meant to allow for a wholesale replacement of the JSON format.

I was going in the wrong direction attempting to use hooks to parse JSON. They exist to augment parsing, but not replace it.