# Elegant way to convert json to list of objects in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a more elegant way to parse a json file containing an array of elements?

Example:

```
import json

contents = ... # read json file

# 'elements_dict' is an array of dictionaries
elements_dict = json.loads(contents)

# 'elements' is a list of Element
elements = [Element(**element) for element in elements_dict]
```

Could the loads function somehow return an array of **Element** instead?

Comment: `object_hook` is what are you looking for. Solved similar question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012059/python-json-load-missing-array-hook-and-parse-callbacks

Comment: Depends. Give an example of the actual data. Do the elements themselves contain more dicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem this way:

```py
elements = json.loads(contents, object_hook=lambda d: Element(**d))
```

Comment: accept it as answer if its correct solution :)